# What is the difference between reg [7:0] a [3:0] and reg [7:0] a [0:3]

Tags: verilog, fpga

So far I have studied verilog HDL **reg [7:0] a [0:3]** means array of 4 **a's** and each **a**  is of 8 bit wide like

```
00110011
01000011
00010011
10000011
```

am i right? then what is the meaning of **reg [7:0] a [3:0]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the two if all you do is access the array one element at a time. There is a difference when you do operations on the array as a whole. In Verilog, the only operations that involves is `$readmemh`/`$writememh` or a access through the C VPI interface.

In SystemVerilog, there are many more operations the ordering could affect, like casting the array to a 32-bit integer. The left index becomes the high order byte.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same thing, the order of the number can be either ascending or descending.
so:

```
reg [7:0] a [0:3] = reg [7:0] a [3:0]
```

Reference:
https://www.verilogpro.com/verilog-arrays-plain-simple/

Comment: The only time I found a difference is if you load an array with $readmem... You get a warning from Cadence if you use `reg [7:0] a [3:0]` but not with `reg [7:0] a [0:3]`. (Never tried it with other simulators)

Comment: What warning did you get?

Comment: Can't remember. It was about seven years ago....I just don't like warnings so I swapped the indices around.

Comment: Ahah never leave out warnings, anyway I’ve seen a great number of syntax declaration for reg array and always the syntax was [array_dim:0] but for clarity I’m going to add a documentation that says how to declare a reg array